# Display inline-block is not applied after display block when using @media in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have an issue with "Configure" (last) list item here in Chrome 35 only (IE9,10,11, FF 30 - ok).
When window width  >480px last list is shown properly;
When window width <=480px last list is shown properly also;

But once I've resized window from ex: 400px to 600px - list item goes down.

Does anybody has an idea why is it so?
(I know now how to workaround it - use position absolute instead of float right. Just curious why is it happening, looks like a Chrome defect)

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>html css</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>

</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#"></a>

        <h1>Contacts Manager</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="search-contact">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search contact here">
        <button>Search</button>
    </div>
</header>

<nav class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Favourite</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My Scrum team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Scrum teams</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Configure</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

h1, h2, ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}

header {
    display: block;
}

header input {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    margin-right: 0;
}

header button {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 0;
    background-color: #ED1C24;
    border: 1px solid #990000;
    padding: 1px 15px;
}

header .logo {
    display: inline-block;
}

header .logo > a:before {
    content: url(../img/serena_logo.gif);
}

header .logo > h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 27px;
    margin: -2px 0 0 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

header .search-contact {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: right;
}

nav li.active {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e51920 1%, #a90507 100%);
}

nav li:not(.active):hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #356aa0 0%,#356aa0 100%);
}

nav li:not(.active):hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

nav li.active a {
    color: #fff;
}

nav.tabs {
    clear: both;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #646464 0%, #323232 100%);
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

nav.tabs ul {
    display: block;
}

nav.tabs a {
    color: #eee;
}

nav.tabs ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-right: -4px;
}

nav.tabs ul > li a {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav.tabs ul > li:last-child {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}

@media all and (max-width: 670px) {

    nav.tabs ul > li {
        padding: 10px 7px;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 480px) {

    nav.tabs ul > li {
        padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin-right: 0;
    }

   nav.tabs ul > li:last-child {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your media query syntax for `(max-width: 480px)` like below.

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
 nav.tabs ul > li {
    padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
    display: block;
    float: none !important;
    margin-right: 0;
 }
 nav.tabs ul > li:last-child {
    display:inline-block !important;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
 } 
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mN7mZ/22/)

Comment: Hello,
Last list item is not shown when window size is less than 480px now.

Comment: Yes. Just now i noticed that one. I have updated my answer. plz check it out.

Comment: Thanks. Now there is another issue.
When window width <=480px the last list item is not highlighted on hover as other list items.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are absolutely right. I just want not to workaround problem like this.

So, is it a chrome defect?

Comment: Not sure about that @Mykola G

Answer (score 0):

That is a very weird bug. I think you might want to submit it to Chrome. I got around it by switching the position of the li that is causing the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/mN7mZ/20/

For the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Configure</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Favourite</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Scrum team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Scrum teams</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
nav.tabs ul > li:first-child {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}

@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    nav.tabs ul > li:first-child {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

So, the first list item is the one on the right. It seems to go back to the correct position after the browser resizes back to wider widths.

Edit:

Obviously the first link will now appear in the wrong position below 480px so I had to do some crazy stuff to get it back at the bottom again. See http://jsfiddle.net/mN7mZ/21/

Comment: Hello,
last list item is not fully highlighted when window width <= 480px.

You can take a look at Suresh Ponnukalai demo where the issue is workarounded using position: absolute.

Do you think it is a chrome defect?

Comment: Thanks, your way also works. Actually there are multiple ways to workaround this issue.